# dynamically add items to checkedlistbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, tchecklistbox

how i can add dynamically  items  with tag to checklistbox, with this code i get the checkbox without value.

```
Dim item As CheckBox
                        While data.Read
                            item = New CheckBox()
                            With item
                                .Name = data.GetString(0)
                                .Tag = data.GetInt64(2)
                                .Text = data.GetString(0)
                            End With
                            ListeBases.Items.Add(item)
                        End While
```

Comment: .Checked = true or false

Comment: Is VB.Net available in VCL? Not just C++ and Delphi. I didn't know.